# Will a positively charged rod undergo simple harmonic motion when displaced by a small amount perpendicular to the axis of a positively charged ring?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, harmonic-oscillator

[image: The attached image shows the motion of the rod for a better visualization.]

I am exploring the behavior of the electric field and its implications, and I am trying to understand the behavior of a positively charged rod when it is placed inside a positively charged ring and is displaced by a small amount perpendicular to the axis of the ring. To help illustrate the situation, I have included a figure to give a rough idea of the setup.

Both the rod and the ring have uniform charge distributions. I am wondering if the rod will undergo simple harmonic motion under these conditions. If so, what is the equation of motion for the rod and what is the period of oscillation? Additionally, how does the amplitude of the oscillation depend on the initial displacement of the rod?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145781/discussion-on-question-by-quantumquipster-will-a-positively-charged-rod-undergo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine in detail the field lines of the ring, you will find that it is not so simple: the field has a radial component directed inwards in the central region and outwards after . So it is not easy to predict the direction of the total radial force on the positively charged wire.

If you want to be more precise, you need to know the radial component of the electric field created by the ring when we are slightly off axis. To obtain it to the first order in $r$, the easiest way is to use Gauss's theorem applied to a small cylinder of radius $r$ and height $dz$. Writing that the flux is zero we find: $$2\pi r dz E_r(r,z) + \pi r^2 (\frac{dE_z(0,z)}{dz})dz =0$$ or :$$E_r(r,z) =  -\frac{r}{2}( \frac{dE_z(0,z)}{dz})$$

I let you calculate the field $E_z(0,z)$ along the axis of the ring as well as its derivative.

The total radial force on the rod will be : $$F_r=-\lambda \frac{r}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty( \frac{dE_z(0,z)}{dz}) dz$$

Everything therefore depends on the sign of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty( \frac{dE_z}{dz}) dz$ surely not very difficult to calculate : it is zero.

So, at first order, the total force is zero. It would be necessary to go to the next order to conclude and if it is stable, the movement will not be harmonic.

EDIT : In the previous calculation, I assumed the rod to be infinite.

If I note $L$ the length of the rod, the total radial force on the rod will be : $$F_r=-\lambda \frac{r}{2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}( \frac{dE_z(0,z)}{dz}) dz=-\lambda r E_z(L/2)$$
Since $E_z(L/2)>0$, the movement will be harmonic !

Note that if the rod is not centered, and still assuming that the movement is simply transverse with a rod that remains vertical, we would have :$$F_r=-\lambda r (E_z(z_2)-E_z(z_1))$$ and the sign of the force should be discussed. But the exercise becomes very academic.

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: I edited my answer as I was assuming the rod infinite. If its lenght is $L$, I no longer find 0. I do not understand your own calculation: I have the impression that you are summing two fields and that you project them and if I understood correctly, this is not correct?

Comment: Cool approach. Nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

Either this situation will be unstable or it will be stable. If it is stable, it will undergo harmonic motion. If it is unstable, a small perturbation from equilibrium will exponentially grow over time. A famous example is a rigid hoop-shaped satellite surrounding the earth. This configuration is unstable, and one side of the hoop will hit the Earth after some time. Interesting to note that we can change the sign of the potential by making the loop and the rod oppositely charged. So if it's unstable in this configuration, it'll be stable in the opposite charge configuration.

Since the potential in this situation is an analytic function of the displacement in the $x$ and $y$ directions, it can only be proportional to the total distance squared, or the the total distance squared to some higher power $(x^2+y^2)^n$. The latter will require fine-tuning, and it is unlikely. If the coefficient is positive, it will be simple harmonic motion. If it's negative, it will be an unstable equilibrium.

We can either find the potential field of the line charge and find the potential energy of the circle sitting in that field or vice versa. I'd recommend choosing the former option because the off-axis potential of a charged loop is annoying to deal with (either an off-axis perturbation or an elliptic integral). One could also perfectly well do the problem with forces, in which case you analyze if the total force between the two pushes them farther off center after a small displacement.

I won't do the math because its possible this is a (pretty difficult) university question, although I'd guess it probably isn't since the diagram is made with MS paint. But make sure you displace the rod *only a small amount* and calculate the potential to second order in that small amount (or first order if you're working with forces). Definitely the integral won't be tractable otherwise. As is the case with all kinds of harmonic motion including springs and pendulums, if the displacement is large compared to the radius of the loop, there will be higher order perturbations to the "force linear with displacement" approximation that gives rise to simple harmonic motion (or exponential growth).

Also note that the question might be *a little bit wrong*. Displacements like this are not the only possible kind of displacement. There are also angular displacements and vertical displacements once you account for the finite length (which is definitely unstable and leads to a slow exponential growth). And the system can be stable with respect to displacements like this, but it might be unstable with respect to angular displacements. If this is the case, it will not do any simple harmonic motion. Within a few oscillations of the stable motion, the unstable motion will have gotten so big that the approximations that gave rise to the harmonic motion are no longer valid. But anyway I suspect the professor - if this is a homework question - only wants you to analyze one type of displacement and ignore the other kind.

Answer (score -1):

inThe charge density of the ring is given by
$$\rho_0(x,y,z)=\lambda_0\delta(z)\delta(x^2+y^2-R^2),$$
where $R$ is the radius of the ring. One could alternatively define it in polar coordinates as
$$
\rho_0(x,y,z)=\lambda_0'\delta(z)\delta(r-R),$$
the constants differ by Jacobian of the transformation, but it is not really important which form is chosen, as the radius is fixed.

The charge density of the rod is
$$
\rho_1(x,y,z)=\lambda_1\delta(x-u)\delta(y),
$$
where $u$ is the displacement from the central axis. Due to the radial symmetry can consider the rod displaced in x direction without loss of generality. One could also easily generalize this to a finite rod.

Finally, the potential energy is
$$
V(u)=\int d^3\mathbf{r}_0\int d^3\mathbf{r}_1\frac{\rho_0(\mathbf{r}_0)\rho_1(\mathbf{r}_1)}{|\mathbf{r}_0-\mathbf{r}_1|}$$
(up to the coefficient specific to your preferred system of units.)

One can now calculate the potential energy and perform expansion in $u$ up to the second order. In fact, performing the expansion first and then integrating is easier, since one can work in polar coordinates and carry integration explicitly (or, in the worst case, look up the integrals in Gradshtein&Ryzhik.)

**Remarks:** (Same as those by @MichaelSeifert in the comments section)

- [Earnshow's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem) tells us that the static configuration of charges is never in a stable equilibrium... but it technically valid only for point charges.
- I assumed that the rod is fixed in such a way that it always remains vertical. If it can deviate from vertical, one has to do a neater job in specifying its displacement - but this is not explicitly stated in the OP.

**Update**
Plugging the charge densities into the integral and using the property of the delta-function we readily arrive at
$$
V(u)=\lambda_0\lambda_1\int dxdy\int dz'\frac{\delta(x^2+y^2-R^2)}{\sqrt{(x-u)^2+y^2+(z')^2}}=\\
\lambda_0\lambda_1\int_0^{+\infty}dr\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{-L}^Ldz\frac{r\delta(r^2-R^2)}{\sqrt{(r\cos\phi-u)^2+r^2\sin^2\phi+z^2}}=\\
\frac{\lambda_0\lambda_1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{-L}^Ldz\frac{1}{\sqrt{(R\cos\phi-u)^2+R^2\sin^2\phi+z^2}},
$$
where I took the rod to have finite length $2L$.
The integral over $z$ can be evaluated analytically, but the resulting expression does require expansion in $u$.

Comment: This seems pretty overcomplicated to me. Every student knows the electric field and potential of a line, and thus can calculate the potential/total force experienced by the hoop from the line charge. Introducing an integral with two complicated delta functions seems like a huge unnecessary step backward.

Comment: @AXensen I don't think it is particularly complicated - it certainly should not be so for a Master or a PhD student. But one can always do it by the pedestrian method of considering small elements of the ring and the rod, which boils down to the same integral. I wanted to provide a hint, without actually solving the  problem, which is a homework one

Comment: as a phd student I assure you we are don't have time to be solving electrostatics problems in purposefully inefficient ways just to prove we aren't "pedestrian"

Comment: @AXensen I don't see how this is "inefficient" - you plug the distributions into the formula and integrate.